# Kendo Grid DropDownList not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Cannot bind  DropDownList in kendo grid.
it works fine if it's not inside the grid.
I try to use

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                      .Name("RegionId")

                                      .OptionLabel("[|[Select...]|]")
                                      .DataTextField("Name")
                                      .DataValueField("Id")
                                      .DataSource(source =>
                                      {
                                          source.Read(read =>
                                          {
                                              read.Action("FindAll", "region")
                                                  .Data("filterRegion");
                                          })
                                           .ServerFiltering(true);

                                      })
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { @required = "" })
                                      .Enable(false)
                                      .AutoBind(false)
                                      .CascadeFrom("CountryId")
                                       .ValuePrimitive(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @required = "" })
    )
```

and its bind as a text box, not drop-down list.
how to make it bind drop-down list?
note: the values do not have a relation in a database I need to just columns and make it by code.

Comment: Are you want to bind dropdownlist as part of `Grid`'s edit template or something like that? Also provide current grid definition while necessary.

Comment: Yes i need as a part of columns in grid 

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserViewModel>()
                              .Name("Users")
                              .Columns(columns =>
                              {
                                 // add DDl here 
                               }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as simple as you may think I am afraid. 
The entire implementation can be found in the [documentation of Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates).

In a few words you have to:

1. Create an object (Text-Value or Id-Label) to bind to your column
2. Create an editor template for this class

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
       .Name("Employee") // The name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property.
       .DataValueField("EmployeeID") // The value of the dropdown is taken from the EmployeeID property.
       .DataTextField("EmployeeName") // The text of the items is taken from the EmployeeName property.
       .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["employees"]) // A list of all employees which is populated in the controller.
   )
   ```
3. Decorate your property with `[UIHint("ObjectEditor")]`

Comment: Thanks my problem with [UIHint("ObjectEditor")]